# How do I insert value of a 'vim global variable' or 'vim internal commands' in text?

Tags: vimscript

I have multiple vim global variables declared in `.vimrc` file like

```
let g:wiki_list = {some dictionary ...}
```

I am able to echo its output in vim exec window using `:echo wiki_list`  **BUT**

How do I read/insert the echoed output in vim text window?

I want to print the output of `:echo some_vim_global_variable` in vim text window under my cursor position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different ways I can think of to do this.

1. You can use the `"=` register. This is like a mini vim calculator that evaluates a string as vimscript code, and returns it in a register. This register can be accessed in normal or insert mode.

   In normal:

   ```
   "=<expr><cr>p
   ```

   In insert:

   ```
   <C-r>=<expr><cr>
   ```

   `<expr>` can be any string of vimscript that evaluates to a string. So in order to get your dictionary variable to evaluate to a string, your `<expr>` should be

   ```
   string(g:wiki_list)
   ```
2. You can use the `redir` command. This basically captures all command line output and stores it into a specified register. Here is sample usage:

   ```
   :redir @a
   :echo g:wiki_list
   "ap
   ```

   I'm not a huge fan of this approach because 1) you'll end up with a bunch of extra newlines, and 2) You have to remember to call `:redir end` afterwards, otherwise your register will get cluttered with a bunch of extra output you don't necessarily want.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thankyou so much :) 1st approach came as total new surprise to me. Thx a ton. Is there a way I can take a look at your `.vimrc` file in-case you might have published it somewhere?

Comment: @avi Glad I could help! My dotfiles are [here](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/dotFiles/blob/master/.vimrc)